# Como podria mostrar el historial de un ID en PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Quisiera hacer un sistema web el cual me muestre el historial de X cliente (ID) ya tengo el crud completo pero en el punto de como crear un historial como me lo pide el cliente lamentablemente no se como se realiza.

Explicacion a detalle de lo que necesito:

El cliente es una llantera va y necesita que cuando  por ejemplo yo almaceno un Dato y el cual se identifica con el ID por ejemplo necesita que cuando le den click  a un Dato ya almacenado en una base de datos le muestre el historial de ese datos.

### Ejemplo en producción:

Guarde a  JUAN el miercoles  -->  y hizo dos entrada y salida en su trabajo el dia la hora y fecha

### Codigo:

#### Actualizar.php

```
<?php
//Compara para ver si existe algo como indica el codigo si no existe un POST
//Mandame hasta el Eelse

if(!empty($_POST)){

/*Compara para ver si los campos agreados al POST (input en el html) esta vacion y si lo estan me manda al else y si no ejecuta la connecion*/
    if(isset($_POST["name"]) &&isset($_POST["lastname"]) &&isset($_POST["email"]) &&isset($_POST["address"]) &&isset($_POST["phone"])){

        if($_POST["name"]!=""&& $_POST["lastname"]!=""&&$_POST["address"]!=""){

    //crea la conexion a la base de datos 
            include "conexion.php";

            /*Ejecuta update a la tabla atravez de la variable $sql y agrega los datos*/
            $sql = "update person set name=\"$_POST[name]\",lastname=\"$_POST[lastname]\",email=\"$_POST[email]\",address=\"$_POST[address]\",phone=\"$_POST[phone]\" where id=".$_POST["id"];

            //se insertan los datos
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            //si ya se termino osea ni no manda nada y todo salio bien me muestra el IF
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Actualizado exitosamente.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";

                //sino me sale el else
            }else{
                print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo actualizar.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

#### agregar.php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["name"]) &&isset($_POST["lastname"]) &&isset($_POST["email"]) &&isset($_POST["address"]) &&isset($_POST["phone"])){
        if($_POST["name"]!=""&& $_POST["lastname"]!=""&&$_POST["address"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $sql = "insert into person(name,lastname,email,address,phone,created_at) value (\"$_POST[name]\",\"$_POST[lastname]\",\"$_POST[email]\",\"$_POST[address]\",\"$_POST[phone]\",NOW())";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Agregado exitosamente.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";
            }else{
                print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo agregar.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

#### Buscar.php

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$user_id=null;
$sql1= "select * from person where name like '%$_GET[s]%' or lastname like '%$_GET[s]%' or address like '%$_GET[s]%' or email like '%$_GET[s]%' or phone like '%$_GET[s]%' ";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>

<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Direccion</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th></th>
</thead>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r["name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["lastname"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["email"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["address"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["phone"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <a href="./editar.php?id=<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Editar</a>
        <a href="#" id="del-<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
        <script>
        $("#del-"+<?php echo $r["id"];?>).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            p = confirm("Estas seguro?");
            if(p){
                window.location="./php/eliminar.php?id="+<?php echo $r["id"];?>;

            }
        });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</table>
<?php else:?>
    <p class="alert alert-warning">No hay resultados</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Creo que en el anterior esta el problema nose porque eso yo creo.

#### tabla.php  - donde muestra los datos

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$user_id=null;
$sql1= "select * from person";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>

<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Direccion</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th></th>
</thead>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r["name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["lastname"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["email"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["address"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["phone"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <a href="./editar.php?id=<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Editar</a>
        <a href="#" id="del-<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
        <script>
        $("#del-"+<?php echo $r["id"];?>).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            p = confirm("Estas seguro?");
            if(p){
                window.location="./php/eliminar.php?id="+<?php echo $r["id"];?>;

            }

        });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</table>
<?php else:?>
    <p class="alert alert-warning">No hay resultados</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hola @gilbertoquintero, lo primero, darte la bienvenida al sitio. Lo segundo y más importante, deberías de agregar una descripción de lo que quieres más detalladamente porque ahora mismo no sabemos que es lo que quiere tu cliente, solo que quiere que se le muestre un historial. Tercero, intenta realizar algo de código o mostrar el CRUD que tienes actualmente y dar razones de por qué no sabes como realizarlo con las especificaciones del cliente. Con todo esto seguro que encuentras a alguien aquí para ayudarte. Si no, tu pregunta tiende a ser cerrada por "no estar claro lo que se pregunta".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tener el historial simplemente debes crear tantos registros como eventos haya. Para el caso de Juan seria:

```
|tabla_persona |  tabla_evento |
|- id          |  id_evento    |  
|- nombre      |  id_persona   |
                  evento       |
```

Estableciendo una relacion de 1 a muchos (1 persona tiene muchos eventos)

Dependera entonces de tu aplicacion que la operacion anadir añada un evento nuevo al id de la persona, en este caso Juan. Y la consulta quedaría algo similar a:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_evento WHERE id_persona = 'IDJUAN';
```

Answer (score 0):

Cre que deberias en primera instancia diagramar las tablas person y las que necesitas auditar agregarndoles las ref del id de la primera.
Ahi tendrias ej:

```
person:
**id**
name
date_insert
date_update

activity
id
**id_person**
accion
date_time
```

Donde el fk es id_person que relaciona la tabla activity con la tabla person

Answer (score -1):

Si con historial te refieres a todo lo que la persona haga dentro de tu aplicación, la idea es si utilizas un framework, desde un controlador base, 
debes de mandar todos los datos hacia una tabla o fichero, por ejemplo que distinga a dicho usuario, esta es una muestra de lo que realize en alguna ocasión

```
public function bitacora($module, $action){
    $bitacora = new Bitacora(array(
    'id_usuario' => $this->data['id_usuario'],
    'modulo' => $module,
    'accion' => $action,
    'parametros' => http_build_query(Input::except('_token'),'',' ,')
    ));
    $bitacora->save();
}
```

Comment: `public function` donde esta la clase hombre?

Comment: No sé...  pero a simple vista parece que no usa framework...